# Read and write a text file in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

How should I read and write a text file from typescript in node.js? 
I am not sure would read/write a file be sandboxed in node.js, if not, i believe there should be a way in accessing file system.

Answer (score 105):

> believe there should be a way in accessing file system.

Include `node.d.ts` using `npm i @types/node`. And then create a new `tsconfig.json` file (`npx tsc --init`) and create a `.ts` file as followed:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
fs.readFileSync('foo.txt','utf8');
```

You can use other functions in `fs` as well : https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

## More

Node quick start : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/nodejs

Comment: With your code I get error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'. Node v.6.4.0 and tsc v.1.8.10. Do you have any advice?

Comment: @WorkingMatt `npm install --save-dev @types/node`

Comment: how comes we use require here and not import?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign just a really really old answer. Updated for latest tech 

Comment: @basarat ah thank you! I thought there might be a specific reason.

Comment: using ES6 syntax it will be `import * as fs from 'fs';`

Comment: Where is foo.txt located?, if I put foo.txt in same directory as .ts file, foo.txt cannot be found I ended up using this: const file = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'foo.txt'), 'utf8'); where path object is imported using: import * as path from 'path';

Comment: fs.writeFileSync is not a function

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.readFileSync is not a function`

Answer (score 28):

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

const file = readFileSync('./filename.txt', 'utf-8');
```

This worked for me.
You may need to wrap the second command in any function or you may need to declare inside a class without keyword `const`.

Comment: "Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations"

Comment: Where do you need to put filename.txt in your example?

Answer (score 16):

First you will need to install **node** definitions for Typescript. You can find the definitions file here:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts

Once you've got file, just add the reference to your `.ts` file like this:

`/// <reference path="path/to/node.d.ts" />`

Then you can code your typescript class that read/writes, using the Node File System module. Your typescript class `myClass.ts` can look like this:

```
/// <reference path="path/to/node.d.ts" />

class MyClass {

    // Here we import the File System module of node
    private fs = require('fs');

    constructor() { }

    createFile() {

        this.fs.writeFile('file.txt', 'I am cool!',  function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            console.log("File created!");
        });
    }

    showFile() {

        this.fs.readFile('file.txt', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            console.log("Asynchronous read: " + data.toString());
        });
    }
}

// Usage
// var obj = new MyClass();
// obj.createFile();
// obj.showFile();
```

Once you transpile your `.ts` file to a javascript ([check out here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html) if you don't know how to do it), you can run your javascript file with node and let the magic work:

```
> node myClass.js
```

Comment: One can just install node types with `npm i --save @types/node`

Answer (score 13):

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "filename.txt"), (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
})
```

EDIT:

consider the project structure:

```
../readfile/
├── filename.txt
└── src
    ├── index.js
    └── index.ts
```

consider the `index.ts`:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

function lookFilesInDirectory(path_directory) {
    fs.stat(path_directory, (err, stat) => {
        if (!err) {
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                console.log(path_directory)
                fs.readdirSync(path_directory).forEach(file => {
                    console.log(`\t${file}`);
                });
                console.log();
            }
        }
    });
}

let path_view = './';
lookFilesInDirectory(path_view);
lookFilesInDirectory(path.join(__dirname, path_view));
```

if you have in the readfile folder and run `tsc src/index.ts && node src/index.js`, the output will be:

```
./
        filename.txt
        src

/home/andrei/scripts/readfile/src/
        index.js
        index.ts
```

that is, it depends on where you run the node.

the [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) is directory name of the current module.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22758091)

Comment: @Daij-Djan I don't think so. I do agree that the answer would be better with a few comments, but really, it's a minimal yet complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter "Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations" when

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
```

**How I solve it**

A bit deviation from Jerome Villiseck's ans

Edit tsconfig.app.json:

```
...
"include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/node/"
]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify: if ever the TS 2307: Cannot find module import error appears: check the tsconfig.json file.

It must contain node_modules

```
{
.....
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
    "node_modules"
  ],
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving the `Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations` error, even with @types/node installed. Here is the full solution that worked for me:

In terminal:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

In the script (`src/fileReader.ts`):

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/node/fs.d.ts" />
import fs from "fs";

let data = fs.readFileSync("myfile.txt")
```

### Version list:

npm version: 9.3.1

node version: 19.5.0

@types/node version: 18.15.0

tsc version: 4.7.4

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write file in ts.
But something how its js.
You can install jquery to run javascript in angular.

```
npm i jquery
```

Import in it in angular.json file and use this code

```
var fileWriter = new Writer();
var fileName = "test_syskey/Test.doc";
fileWriter.removeFile(fileName, function(err,url) {
    if (err) {
        resp.error("Write failed");
    } else {
        resp.success(url);
    }
});
```