# How to reference node fs API with electron in typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron

I've created an electron app based on [this link](http://tphangout.com/angular-2-desktop-apps-with-electron) (but using recent modules).

I want to create a simple desktop app, I need to open some local files. I know that there is the node fs API for this, but I'm have problems with referencing it correctly.

Here is what I tried:

- Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643107/read-and-write-a-text-file-in-typescript) queston in Stackoverflow, I tried to import and use fs like this:

  ```
  ///<reference path="../typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
  import fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFileSync('foo.txt','utf8');
  ```

  As a result, I got a **Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs'** when I called *npm run build*
- Then I added the following lines to *webpack.config.js* (I read it somewhere):

  ```
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  },
  ```

  then *npm run build* command was OK, but I see the following error at runtime in electron's developer tool: **TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function**

I'm new to this topic, and I would appreciate if someone could help me how to reference node's fs API correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `target: 'electron-renderer'` in your Webpack config, if you still have issues after that take a look at https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

Comment: Thanks a lot! Setting `target: 'electron-renderer'` in Webpack config solved my problem!

Comment: Please provide all necessary information in your answer instead of just linking to it.

Comment: Wonder how does this solution apply to angular 8 + electron