# How to populate SQLite through a .sql file?

Tags: sql, sqlite, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a `.sql` file and need to insert all the records in my sqlite on the device.

File content `mydb.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE tblVeiculo (VeiculoId INT, Codigo [TEXT(9)], Fabricante [TEXT(255)], Modelo [TEXT(255)], AnoInicial INT, AnoFinal INT, Portas INT, Combustivel [VARCHAR(30)], NrMotorObstruido BOOLEAN);
INSERT INTO tblVeiculo (VeiculoId, Codigo, Fabricante, Modelo, AnoInicial, AnoFinal, Portas, Combustivel, NrMotorObstruido) VALUES (1, '001034066', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 SB(E-TRONIC)(URB.) DIES 2P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 2, 'DIES', 1);
INSERT INTO tblVeiculo (VeiculoId, Codigo, Fabricante, Modelo, AnoInicial, AnoFinal, Portas, Combustivel, NrMotorObstruido) VALUES (2, '001034078', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 LE(E-TRONIC)(RODOV.) DIES 1P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 1, 'DIES', 0);
INSERT INTO tblVeiculo (VeiculoId, Codigo, Fabricante, Modelo, AnoInicial, AnoFinal, Portas, Combustivel, NrMotorObstruido) VALUES (3, '001034080', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 LE(E-TRONIC)(RODOV.C/AR) DIES 1P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 1, 'DIES', 0);
INSERT INTO tblVeiculo (VeiculoId, Codigo, Fabricante, Modelo, AnoInicial, AnoFinal, Portas, Combustivel, NrMotorObstruido) VALUES (4, '001034091', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 LE(E-TRONIC)(URBANO) DIES 2P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 2, 'DIES', 0);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
```

How to populate SQLite through a .sql file using TypeScript?

Comment: Simply read the file one line at a time and execute each line as a separate SQL command. Until you reach the line which begins with COMMIT. Possibly, enclose all in a transaction.

Comment: @Rotwang How could I do that? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Rotwang It's not java, it's typescript.

Comment: @Rotwang Did you see them as tags? I'll change it as tags.

Comment: My bad. I guess this does... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643107/read-and-write-a-text-file-in-typescript