# How to read csv file in Angular-4 assets

Tags: node.js, angular, csv, typescript

I am new to angular-4 and I want to read a csv file from angular-4 assets directory, file size 5mb and I dont't want to read this file from django back-end server because this file is to show only demo graphs and I don't need to send 5mb extra request to server, thanks
currently I follow this stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643107/read-and-write-a-text-file-in-typescript)

**Files Reading**

```
private fs = require('fs');

readCsvData () {
    let allText = this.fs.readFileSync('assets/demo-Results.csv', 'utf8');
    console.log(allText)
    // this.extractData(allText);
}
```

**Error is :**

> ShowDemoResultsComponent.html:17 ERROR TypeError: this.fs.readFileSync
>   is not a function
>       at ShowDemoResultsComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/show-demo-results/show-demo-results.component.ts.ShowDemoResultsComponent.readCsvData
>   (show-demo-results.component.ts:119)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ShowDemoResultsComponent.html:17)
>       at handleEvent (core.es5.js:12023)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13493)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13081)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8615)
>       at core.es5.js:9226
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.es5.js:2651)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - Read a file and parse its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581687/angular-read-a-file-and-parse-its-content)

Comment: Its not, In your mention reference, they read file from event that is bind with file upload btn but in my case file is not uploaded by upload btn, I just want to read file from assets. for example  ` let fileReader = new FileReader();  fileReader.read('filepath', 'r')` kind of thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case you use the new HttpClient class (@angular/common/http), then you will have to set the responseType to 'text', otherwise the HttpClient class would try to interpret the content as json and raise a SyntaxError...

```
e.g.:
this.http.get('assets/file.csv', {responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Why does this work? It only works from assets folder however. If I create a directory under app/ and read from that location, it doesn't work.

Comment: `{responseType}` maded the difference for me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

I finally find a answer
**Here is how I done it:**

```
csvUrl = 'assets/demo-Results.csv';
readCsvData () {
      this.http.get(this.csvUrl)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data.text())
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err)
          });
  }
```

Comment: How can I download this file?