# Writing a text file in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I want to write a text file in Ionic and I've tried many different methods and neither of them works

```
import { Filesystem, Directory, Encoding } from '@capacitor/filesystem';
writeSecretFile = async () => {
    await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: 'secrets/text.txt',
      data: "This is a test",
      directory: Directory.Documents,
      encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
    });
  };
```

In this case, My app wont even start,  [source](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem)

```
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';
  fun() {
    this.fileOpener
      .open('./filer.pdf', 'application/pdf')
      .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
      .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
  }
}
```

this wont work either  [Stackbuiltz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bdracg?file=pages/home/home.ts)
All the efforts are highly appreciated

Comment: this wasn't helpful either  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643107/read-and-write-a-text-file-in-typescript#:~:text=import%20%7B%20readFileSync%20%7D%20from%20'fs,a%20class%20without%20keyword%20const%20.

Comment: Please add more details. Its a little vague saying it just doesn't work

Comment: iOS or Android?

Comment: @misha130 I gave the link to stackbuiltz where the code is written please take a look, and as a result the app wont even start, no error messages no nothing at all :((

Comment: @guzmanoj for now testing on the browser but later on for android

Comment: do you have imported the package in the `app.module.ts`?

Comment: @SadafShafi it won't work on your browser.

Comment: @guzmanoj According to the docs it does work in PWAs, I assume they're using IndexedDB.

Comment: @Thomas genuine question... where? 
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem

Comment: @RSD thanks a lot
I just did that and it worked, would you please write it as an answer so that I'd accept it and close the issue

Comment: @guzmanoj Apparently I was looking at the v2 docs which has icons. But there is a web version in the repo: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/main/filesystem/src/web.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to import the package into your `app.module.ts`