# explicitly closing a file after readFileSync

Tags: typescript, file, io, fclose

Our system has (evidently) too many open files:

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files
```

Should we explicitly close files after:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
for (const filename in filenames) {
  const text = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString();
  // explictly close the file? how?
}
```

It seems that canonical answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33643701/3357352)) don't mention it.

Comment: I believe you don't need to close it when you are using `fs.readFileSync` (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_file_system.htm#Closing%20a%20File). What version of node are you using?

Comment: @RobertRendell, `v18.12.1`

Comment: I'm also struggling to see why you would get that error using `readFileSync`. Are you reading files anywhere else in your code?

Comment: You mean reading *other* files right? not necessarily the same ones (same ones I'm sure the answer is no)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that wraps the `readFileSync` with `openSync` and `closeSync`:

```js
import { openSync, closeSync, readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs'

const d1 = openSync('input.json', 'r')
const data = readFileSync(d1).toString();
closeSync(d1)

const parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
const filenames = new Array<string>();

for (const n of parsedData) {
  filenames.push(n['name']);
}

let mydata = [];
for (const filename of filenames) {
  const d = openSync(filename, 'r')
  mydata.push(readFileSync(d).toString())
  closeSync(d)
}

console.log(mydata.length)
```

It opens + reads + closes 100,000 files in a loops without any problem:

```
$ grep -rn "\"name\": " input.json | wc -l
100001
$ npx tsc main.ts                         
$ node ./main.js                          
100001
```

Comment: Ah fixed! Nice work